# CSS I cannot make an item to go behind another item

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a navbar dropdown. And I am experiencing this issue.

This is the navbar that is dropped down, however, during the dropdown the blue banner got covered by my pink pinkdown menu.

[image]

Here is the dropdown menu during it's animation
[image]

My html and css for these 2 component is like this, may I know if anyone knows how can i make the pink dropdown menu go behind the green banner? Thanks!

```
    <nav className="nav-main">
      <div className="nav-spacer-side"></div>
      <img src={jssLogo} alt="JSS Logo" className="nav-org-logo"></img>
      <div className="nav-spacer-center"></div>
      <ul className="nav-menu">
        <li className="nav-item">About</li>
        <li className="nav-item">Sub-Club</li>
        <li className="nav-item">Events</li>
        <li className="nav-item">Sponsors</li>
        <li className="nav-item">Contact</li>
      </ul>

      <div className="nav-spacer-side"></div>

      <div className="nav-burger" onClick={toggleBurger}>
        <span className="nav-burger-bar"></span>
        <span className="nav-burger-bar"></span>
        <span className="nav-burger-bar"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```
.nav-main {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: green;
}

.nav-menu {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 2s;
}
```